# Proving the formula of a truncated pyramid - follow up question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been asked the following problem and am stuck.

A fustrum of a square based pyramid is a square pyramid with the top sliced off (I understand this so far).

$H$ is the height of the full pyramid and $h$ is the height of the fustrum.

Find the volume of the large pyramid which has a square base side of $X$ cm.

My answer is $(1/3)X^2\cdot H$

Find the volume of the small pyramid which has a square base of $x$ cm

My answer is $(1/3)x^2\cdot (H-h).$

Show that the relationship between $H$ and $h$ is given by $H = Xh/(X-x).$

I have reviewed the answer for the proof of the formula for the volume of a truncated pyramid [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933558/prove-the-truncated-pyramid-volume-formula)

What I don't understand is why the ratio of the height of the small pyramid to the large one is the same as the ratio of the small base to the big base.

ie why 
$$
x:X = (H-h):H
$$
If someone can explain that to me it would go a long way to me being able to answer the question above and showing why the volume of the fustrum is 
$$
1/3\cdot h(X^2 + x^2 + X\cdot x)
$$
I need to show this using algebra as we haven't started learning calculus yet.

I tried to comment in the link to the answer referred to but I didn't have enough reputation points as I just signed up - hence the new post.

With thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the previous relation
$$\frac{h}{H} = \frac{X - x}{X} = 1 - \frac{x}{X}.$$ 
Thus
$$\frac{x}{X} = 1 - \frac{h}{H} = \frac{H - h}{H}.$$